# How to pass arguments among R functions?

Tags: r, function, arguments

I have 2 small functions (`DoAnalysis()` and `ProcessRes()`) and 1 final function (`PerformSim()`) which will call the 2 small functions. The detailed sample functions are listed below.

Each function contains a unique argument (non-overlapping argument):

- Function `PerformSim()` contains 1 unique argument `nsim`;
- Function `DoAnalysis()` contains 1 unique argument `obj`;
- Function  `ProcessRes()` contains 1 unique argument `results`

For the remained arguments, the function `DoAnalysis()` has the complete set, function `DoAnalysis()` contains a subset of the arguments of function `DoAnalysis()`, hence, function `PerformSim()` need to contain the information to call both functions `DoAnalysis()` and `ProcessRes()`.

The following code does not work since I am not sure how to properly pass the arguments among functions.

Please help and thanks so much in advance for your assistance.

```
library(purrr)
DoAnalysis <- function(obj, nS1 = 40, nS2 = 40, nS3 = 20, cutoff) {

    cumS2 <- nS1 + nS2      ## this is the total number of patients at the end of Stage 2
    nmax  <- cumS2 + nS3    ## this is the total number of patients at the end of study

    ## compute number of events for 1st stage
    Res_n <- sum(obj[1:nS1]) ## this is the number of response in Stage 1

    ## compute number of events for 2nd stage
    Res_n2 <- sum(obj[1:cumS2]) ## this is the number of response in Stage 2

    ### Now, it is the final analysis
    Res_F <- sum(obj[1:nmax]) ## this is the number of response in Final

    list(Res_n, Res_n2, Res_F)
}

ProcessRes <- function(results, cutoff){
  part1 <- part2 <- part3 <- c()

  for (i in 1:length(results)){
     part1 <- as.vector(c(part1, results[[i]][[1]]))
     part2 <- as.vector(c(part2, results[[i]][[2]]))
  }
  resultsTypeI <- as.data.frame(cbind(part1, part2, part3))

  names(resultsTypeI) <- c("Res_n", "Res_n2")

  resultsTypeI$fulFlag <- ifelse(resultsTypeI$Res_n2 < cutoff, 1, 0)
  R_1 <- mean(resultsTypeI$fulFlag)   

  return(c(R_1))
}

set.seed(20201022)

PerformSim <- function(nsim, nS1 = 40, nS2 = 40, nS3 = 20, cutoff = 26){
  ## this is the simulation  
  total <- nS1 + nS2 + nS3
  SimuTypeI <- map(1:nsim, ~rbinom(total, 1, 0.4))
  results <- map(SimuTypeI, ~DoAnalysis(.x))
  ProcessRes(results = results)
}
PerformSim(nsim = 1000)
```

Comment: Where are the variables `R_2`,`R_3`,`R_4`,`R_5` defined?

Comment: You could use do.call and pass arguments as a list to each function.

Comment: @Shan, thanks for pointing it out. The code was revised from an existing code, forgot to change this part. Now, it is updated in the question to only keep R_1.

Comment: @Econ_matrix could you please give a bit more details? I am not sure how to handle this line of code by passing argument since it call the function DoAnalysis                                                                 
 results <- map(SimuTypeI, ~DoAnalysis(.x))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your function definitions and arguments looks good but in your `PerformSim()` function definition you have to pass the argument `cutoff` in `ProcessRes()`. Like this.

```
PerformSim <- function(nsim, nS1 = 40, nS2 = 40, nS3 = 20, cutoff = 26){
  ## this is the simulation  
  total <- nS1 + nS2 + nS3
  SimuTypeI <- map(1:nsim, ~rbinom(total, 1, 0.4))
  results <- map(SimuTypeI, ~DoAnalysis(.x))
  ProcessRes(results = results, cutoff)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This works perfectly. I was trying to use the ... in the sub-functions, like ProcessRes, but really do not understand the way to proper use in calling them.

Comment: @TStat Whenever you are calling a function, just make sure that you have all the undefined arguments in it.